# How to parse and get String to Another Jframe - JAVA

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to parse String to another frame Using JAVA

i have 2 jFrames. jFrame1 have 1 text field and jFrame 2 have 1 text field. i want to parse jFrame1 text filed's text to jframe2's text field.

#### It's look like this : But this is not code :(

```
jFrame2.textfield1.setText(jFrame1.textfield1.gettext());
```

### Anyone know how to parse String to another frame Using JAVA?

#### Thanks in advance!

Comment: so whats your question?

Comment: how to parse string to another jFrame ?

Comment: Are both these jframes mutually accessible? The code that you have given, why is that not working?

Comment: that code is not working. coz cant do that thing using that code. it's just code(VB6 can do it like that code). do you know how to parse String to Another frame using java ?

Comment: Other than the fact that it's `getText()` rather than `gettext()`, I don't see why this wouldn't work.
Where are you calling this from?

Comment: "Parse" implies some sort of (syntax) analysis. You just want to copy the content from one to another. Answer is "do it", couldn't be simplier. What's the problem  you are encountering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have two separate GUIs on the screen at the same time because both textFields have the same reference, each JFrame will be a Object in its own right.
Therefore the only way to access another objects variables is with its methods.
Create a setter method in jFrame2 to change the textField in question.
See Working code below.

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
 import java.awt.event.*;


public class JframeLink {




    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new JframeOneGui();
        new JframeTwoGui();
    }


    //JFrame one Object
    public static class JframeOneGui extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    {
        JPanel jPanelOne = new JPanel();
        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField("Message for transfer");
        JButton buttonOne = new JButton("Transfer");

        public JframeOneGui()
        {
            //setup swing components
            textField1.setSize(100,10);
            buttonOne.addActionListener(this);
            //setup jPanelOne
            jPanelOne.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanelOne, 1));
            jPanelOne.add(textField1);
            jPanelOne.add(buttonOne);
            //setup JframeOneGui
            this.add("Center",jPanelOne);
            this.setLocation(25,25);
            this.setTitle("JframeOneGui");
            this.setSize(200,200);
            this.setResizable(false);
            this.setVisible(true);
        }


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getSource() == buttonOne)
            {
                //Here we are calling JframeTwoGui's Setter method
                JframeTwoGui.setTextFieldOne(textField1.getText());
            }
        }   

    }

    //JFrame two Object
    public static class JframeTwoGui extends JFrame
    {
        JPanel jPanelOne = new JPanel();
        static JTextField textField1 = new JTextField();

        public JframeTwoGui()
        {


            jPanelOne.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanelOne, 1));
            jPanelOne.add(textField1);

            this.add("Center",jPanelOne);
            this.setLocation(300,25);
            this.setTitle("JframeTwoGui");
            this.setSize(200,200);
            this.setResizable(false);
            this.setVisible(true);

        }

        //Setter to change TextFieldOne in this Object
        public static void setTextFieldOne(String text)
        {
            textField1.setText(text);

        }
    }




}
```

Comment: there is have two java classes. 1st one is frm_one and 2nd one is frm_two. i want to parse frm_one jtextfield's text to frm_two jtextfield.

Comment: i'm using netBeans IDE. i'm created 2 jframes, frm_one and frm_two.

Comment: same difference just place classes(JFrame classes) outside main class